# Issues regarding JSON Array

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, cxf

I have an array attribute in JSON object. These Arrays shows square brackets '[ ]' when data has multiple elements in array.But if there is a single element in data array,it shows curly brackets '{ }' in JSON.So is there any better solutions to have that square brackets '[ ]'when single elements is only there?I am using CXF Framework.

Or

What is the reason behind curly brackets '{ }' and no square brackets when single elements is only there?I am using CXF Framework.

Comment: What lib do you use for working with JSON? Do you use [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)?

Comment: And array is denoted by square brackets, an object is denoted by curly braces. The two are not interchangeable and have completely different meanings.

Comment: I am using JSON Object and if there is only single data there is only curly braces shown like-{"1":"2012-04-26"},if multiple data is there,then  square brackets are there like[{"1":"2012-04-26"},{"1":"2013-04-25"}]

Comment: @Prabhathkesav what lib do you use? And show code. There are plenty libs for working with json in java.

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov...Jettison lIbrary

Comment: @Prabhathkesav . It is weird. What version do you use?

Comment: @ Nikita Beloglazov versions are jettison 1.3.1, CXF-2.3.2

Comment: @Prabhathkesav it works with collection and single element: http://pastebin.com/j8RbYkc3 . Show your example.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov But what in case of JSON Arrays?

Comment: @Prabhathkesav the same. JSON object inside `[]` brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have single element still use square brackets like this:

```
[{"somename":"somevalue"}]
```

Square brackets are used to seperate the elements therefore if there is only one element you can do with curly brackets

Comment: Only if you have an array of *objects*. An array can contain numbers or strings, e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5]` or `["this","that","other"]`

Comment: I am using JSON Object and if there is only single data there is only curly braces shown like-{"1":"2012-04-26"}...NO SQUARE BRACKET IS THERE,if multiple data is there,then square brackets are there like[{"1":"2012-04-26"},{"1":"2013-04-25"}]

Answer (score 0):

Think of an array in an json object as a second json object in a json object. What you got then is for example this single json-'array'

```
{
    "this": "is a single object",
    "another" : "object in a json array"
}
```

See at the 'another' part as filled with a second json object.

```
{
    "this": "is a single object",
    "although": [
        {
            "this": "is an object",
            "and this": "another object in a second object",
            "and this": "another object in a second object"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the second case "although" is this json object.

```
{
      "this": "is an object",
      "and this": "another object in a second object",
      "and this": "another object in a second object"
}
```

Just to let json know it is an array (another json object) there are the `[` and `]`.